# how to inherit parent constructor functionality into child constructor

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, inheritance, polymorphism

I have written a NewsApi() class and created a child class of it Cricket(). Below are the snippets of code:
[Class NewsApi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQnAE.png)

```
class NewsApi(object):

    def __init__(self, parameter, country):
        self.parameter = parameter
        self.country = country
        self.top_headlines = 
        newsapi.get_top_headlines(q=self.parameter,country=self.country)
        self.description = []
        self.url = []
        self.image_link = []
        self.title = []
        self.sources = []
        for article in self.top_headlines['articles']:
            self.description.append(article['description'])
            self.url.append(article['url'])
            self.image_link.append(article['urlToImage'])
            self.title.append(article['title'])
            self.sources.append(article['source']['name'])
```

So i want to create a Cricket Class inherited from NewsApi() class. Also i want to add the specific functionality of constructor of NewsApi Class in the Cricket() class.
As i don't want to write the same code again in the Cricket() class constructor.

```
class CricketNews(NewsApi):
    get_every = newsapi.get_everything(q="Cricket",
                                        from_parameter=yesterday_date,  
                                        to=today_date,
                                        language='en',
                                        sort_by='relevancy',
                                        page=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Super method to call methods of super class.

```
class CricketNews(NewsApi):
    def __init__(self, parameter, country):
        super(CricketNews, self).__init__(parameter, country)
        # your init code.

       get_every = newsapi.get_everything(q="Cricket",
                                    from_parameter=yesterday_date,  
                                    to=today_date,
                                    language='en',
                                    sort_by='relevancy',
                                    page=2)
```